# How to check each value in particular group and set flag status?

Tags: mysql, sql

Assume I have a Table "Emp"

```
Dpt_ID | E_ID | E_Status

A1 | 00200 | H
A1 | 00200 | M
A1 | 00400 | H
A1 | 00400 | M
A2 | 00300 | L
A2 | 00300 | M
A2 | 00400 | L
A2 | 00400 | L
```

Data needs to grouped according to Dpt_ID, If any E_ID under that Dpt_ID has status =H, then Set Flag=High. Similarly, if any E_ID under that Dpt_ID has status =M, then Set Flag=Medium else Low.

Currently I have written following query, but with group by function it checks only 1st row :

```
SELECT Dpt_ID,E_ID,E_Status,(CASE
            WHEN E_Status = "H" THEN 'High'
            WHEN E_Status = "M" THEN 'Medium'
            ELSE 'Low'
            END) AS Flag
FROM Emp 
group by Dpt_ID
```

How do I check each value in Dpt_ID group to see if it's H/M/L ?

E.g. Target should be displayed as

```
Dpt_ID | Flag

A1 | High
A2 | Medium
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you can't use `MAX()` directly because you have arbitrary char values, one option is assigning a weight to your values so you can use `MAX()`, and then get the flag using the weight values:

```
SELECT Dpt_ID,
  CASE MAX(CASE E_Status WHEN 'H' THEN 2 WHEN 'M' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
       WHEN 2 THEN 'High' WHEN 1 THEN 'Medium' ELSE 'Low' END AS Flag
FROM Emp 
group by Dpt_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

You are close.  You can do:

```
SELECT Dpt_ID, E_ID, E_Status,
      (CASE WHEN MAX(E_Status = 'H') THEN 'High'
            WHEN MAX(E_Status = 'M') THEN 'Medium'
            ELSE 'Low'
       END) AS Flag
FROM Emp 
GROUP BY Dpt_ID;
```